# Program Flow in some Haskell Code

Tags: haskell

i have a haskell function, somehow related to infix operators.

```
(<+) :: Hand -> Hand -> Hand
Empty <+ hand = hand
hand <+ Empty = hand
(Add card hand1) <+ h2 = Add card (hand1 <+ h2)
```

The first two lines after the function signature are pretty understandable but the last one is a bit hard for me to understand how it flow

The purpose of the function is to create an operator that when given two hands, it adds one hand onto the other. By "Hand" i can mean a collection of cards.

The definition of card and Hand types is as follows

```
data Card = Card { rank :: Rank, suit :: Suit } deriving (Eq, Show)
data Hand = Empty | Add Card Hand deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Comment: I don't see multiple lines in the text. Please format code properly. Moreover you didn't explain your problem. I see only statements and no question in the text.

Comment: It seems you just recreated lists (with `(<+)` instead of `++`, `Add` instead of `(:)` and `Empty` instead of `[]`) - so is this some kind of homework or why don't you want to use just lists?

Comment: Add the definition for `Hand`, please. Must be something like `data Hand = Empty | Add Card Hand`. That way, your homework attracts fewer downvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last one is the usual recursive case:

If your *left* hand consists of one card `card` **plus** some *tail-hand*  `hand1` then you can *concatenate* your *right* hand `h2` (naming seems strange) by adding `card` in front of what you get when you you *concatenate* `hand1` and `h2` (recursivley) - which is exactly `hand1 <+ h2`

The important thing is that the *left-hands* get smaller so the recursion can finally stop - you just push `(<+)` deeper in there (by pulling `Add` out) till you get to one of the `Empty`-cases.

Maybe an example helps:

```
(Add l1 (Add l2 Empty)) <+ (Add r1 Empty)
{ last case }
= Add l1 ((Add l2 Empty) <+ (Add r1 Empyt))
{ last case for the inner part }
= Add l1 (Add l2 (Empty <+ (Add r1 Empty)))
{ first case  inner }
= Add l1 (Add l2 (Add r1 Empty))
```

which is just a hand with `l1,l2,r1` (or so I guess)

Comment: what is my left hand doesnt consist of one card but rather lets say 4-5 cards....am having problems visualizing it in real logic.

Comment: the example above has 2-cards in your left hand (to be honest: I am just to lazy to add 5 and show 3 steps more - they would be just the same as the the first 2 steps here) - if you are talking about the right hand: it does not really matter (as you can see it's value never changes - you could replace `Add r1 Empty` with anything and the steps will not change)

Comment: PS: what is **real** logic?

Comment: Well, the ultimate logic was adding two decks together but using the infix operator which i wasnt soo much well versed with....but i think now am starting to grasp something on why they are actually used